# convert mysql query contains sum and group_concat to mongodb query

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to convert below mysql query to mongodb query.

```
SELECT substring(o.schedule_datetime,1,4) 'Year',
SUM(IF(o.order_status in ('SUCCESS','#SUCCESS'),1,0)) 'SUCCESS'
FROM (
      select group_concat(distinct ifnull(os.order_status,'') order by os.order_status 
      separator '#') 'order_status',schedule_datetime
      from order_summary os group by order_number
     )o group by 1 desc;
```

For Example: I have sample table

```
id order_number product_number order_status schedule_datetime
1  001          001.1          SUCCESS      20180103
2  001          001.2          SUCCESS      20180102
3  111          111.1          SUCCESS      20171225
4  111          111.2          SUCCESS      20171224
5  222          222.1          INPROGRESS   20171122
6  222          222.2          SUCCESS      20171121
```

I get the output using above mysql query for order status SUCCESS

```
Year SUCCESS
2018 1
2017 1
```

I have used separator(#) to combine multiple statues as string and get the desired result by status, to get INPROGRESS i will be just changing SUM funtion as shown below :

```
SUM(IF(o.order_status in ('INPROGRESS','INPROGRESS#SUCCESS', '#INPROGRESS','#INPROGRESS#SUCCESS'),1,0)) 'INPROGRESS'
```

I have tried to write the mongodb query, but got stuck how to combine sum and if condition as well group_concat with seperator as i used in mysql query.

```
db.order_summary.aggregate([ 

 { "$project" :
    { "orderDate" : 1 , "subOrderDate" : { "$substr" : [ "$order_date" , 0 , 4]},
        "order_number":"$order_number"
    },

 } ,
 { "$group":{
     "_id": { "order_number" : "$order_number", "Year": "$subOrderDate", "order_status":{"$addToSet":{"$ifNull":["$order_status",'']}}}
    }
 },
 { "$group": {
     "_id": "$_id.Year", "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
 },
 { "$sort" : { "_id" : -1}}
 ])
```

Anyone help will be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Group_Concat kind of functionality in mongodb.

You can compare arrays for matching values in last group with [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator in 3.4 version.

First `$group` to get all the distinct order status for a combination for order number and order status.

`$sort` to sort the order statuses.

Second `$group` to push all the sorted status values by order number.

Final `$group` to compare the statuses for each year against the input list of status and output total count for all matches.

```
db.order_summary.aggregate([{"$project":{
  "schedule_datetime":1,
  "order_number":1,
  "order_status":{"$ifNull":["$order_status",""]}
}},
{"$group":{
  "_id":{
    "order_number":"$order_number",
    "order_status":"$order_status"
   },
  "schedule_datetime":{"$first": "$schedule_datetime"} 
}},
{"$sort":{"_id.order_status": 1}},
{"$group":{
   "_id":{
    "order_number":"$_id.order_number"
   },
  "schedule_datetime":{"$first": "$schedule_datetime"},
  "order_status":{"$push": "$_id.order_status"}
}},
{"$group":{
  "_id":{"$substr":["$schedule_datetime",0,4]},
  "count":{
    "$sum":{
      "$cond": [
        {"$in": ["$order_status",[["SUCCESS"], ["","SUCCESS"]]]}, 
        1,
        0]
    }
  }
}},
{"$sort":{"_id":-1}}])
```

Comment: thanks it working for single status, but how to combine multiple status with separator(which i used in mysql query). I tried adding {"$in": ["$status",[["INPROGRES"], ["INPROGRESSUCCESS"],["INPROGRES"]]]}, but no luck . I just updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: Np. I've rewritten aggregation query to mimic mysql query exactly and did test the query with provided data on both mysql and mongodb and results match exactly. Try `{"$in": ["$order_status",[["INPROGRESS"],["INPROGRESS","SUCCESS"], ["SUCCESS"], ["","SUCCESS"]]]}`. Although to be honest I don't clearly understand the intent. For ex: Why are you grouping by order number when your final output is only grouped by year ? Are you sure you don't want the final output group by both year and order number ? I'm afraid we may be missing something here.Please make sure you run all the tests.

Comment: Actually, have the requirement to get the total count of order which got success for each product_number. So when we say all product_number is success then only that order is completed, like that if any of the product_number is in-progress, it should go into  in-progress count. Hope i explained clearly.

Comment: Makes sense. So you need multiple counts each for successful and inprogress orders ? The current query only output count for successful orders.

Comment: yeah, there are many statuses but i have disclosed here two for example.  You have given for INPROGRESS as well, I will test and let you know.

Comment: Cool but I think you will need two separate counts, one for each success and inprogess. Something like `{"$group":{
  "_id":{"$substr":["$schedule_datetime",0,4]},
  "completed":{
    "$sum":{
      "$cond": [
        {"$in": ["$order_status",[["SUCCESS"], ["","SUCCESS"]]]}, 
        1,
        0]
    }
  },
  "in-progress":{
    "$sum":{
      "$cond": [
        {"$in": ["$order_status",[["INPROGRESS"],["INPROGRESS","SUCCESS"]]]}, 
        1,
        0]
    }
  }
}}}`

Comment: Yes, you are write, but i have show these all on report and call through API to take each statuses count separately and put it :)

Comment: Let me know if I can help you anyways.

Comment: Sure, Wat i am trying currenty, as above query is taking the statues sequence in desc order for example(if SUCCESS,INPROGRESS is there and i give INPROGRESS,SUCCESS then it works fine but when i give SUCCESS, INPROGRESS it returns the count 0).  I would like to give all the status, if matches 1 or more statuses from the list just give the count. For example: statuses are success, inprogress, on_hold if i give any combination like [success, inprogress, on_hold] or [inprogress, on_hold, success] it should matches any of the statuses and give the count

Comment: Is it a single array for comparison ? Or is it array of array for comparison ? against order statuses. For single array comparison you can try `{"$gt":[{"$size":{"$setIntersection":["$order_status",["SUCCESS","INPROGRESS"]]}},0]}` in cond. For array of arrays comparison you have to iterate each array and compare against the order status and find if there is a match `{"$gt":[{"$size":{$filter: {input: [["SUCCESS"], ["","SUCCESS"]],cond: {{"$gt":[{"$size":{"$setIntersection":["$order_status","$$this"]}},0]} }}}},0]}`

Comment: Try `"count":{ "$sum":{ "$gt":[{"$size":{$filter: {input: [["SUCCESS"], ["","SUCCESS"]],cond: {"$gt":[{"$size":{"$setIntersection":["$order_status","$$th‌is"]}}, 0]} }}, 0]} }`. I had extra parenthesis.

Comment: Yeah thanks,  i did that, so only i removed comment. Now i am trying to modify the query to print order_number also in ouptut : `"_id":{"$substr":["$schedule_datetime",0,4], "order_number":"$_id.order_number"}` But it displays the order_number which has count 0 also, i want to only print >0 .

Comment: $gt is already added but when i get the result it also includes record which has count 0, to get result which matched that is count > 0 like this year, order_number, count 2017, 001, 1. i have added below query after calculating $sum of matched status. `{"$group":{
    "_id": "$_id.scheduled_datetime",
        "order_details": { "$push": { "order_number": "$_id.order_number","count": { $gt: [ "$count", 0 ] }}} 
}},` Could you please suggest

Comment: Please create a separate question for comments not related to original question in future. Is count a matched status count or a new count which is order_number count ? If former you just need a $match stage after $group ( `{$match:{count:{$gt:0}}}`). If later you will need to update the $group to push the order number array followed by $addFields +  $match to count the items in array and add $gt condition. `"_id":{"$substr":["$schedule_datetime",0,4], count:...., "order_numbers": { "$push": { "$_id.order_number"}}`, `{$addFields:{$size:"$order_numbers"}}`, `{$match:{order_numbers:{$gt:0}}}`

Comment: sorry for that, sure i will create a new question.

Comment: I have create a new question, please look into that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299177/compare-multiple-values-inside-aggregation-and-display-result-in-array-in-mongod

Comment: I will accept the answer as it is working correctly for the raised question