# compare multiple values inside aggregation and display result in array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following table :-

```
id order_number product_number order_status schedule_datetime
1  001          001.1          SUCCESS      20180103
2  001          001.2          SUCCESS      20180102
3  111          111.1          SUCCESS      20171225
4  111          111.2          SUCCESS      20171224
5  222          222.1          INPROGRESS   20171122
6  222          222.2          ON_HOLD      20171121
7  222          222.3          PARTLY_SUCCESS 20171121
```

What i am trying here, if any of the product_number matches the status given in the query, it should display the year and list of order_numbers.

Input 1: order_status = SUCCESS, below output should come

```
{
"order_statuses" : [
    "SUCCESS"
],
"year" : "2018",
"order_number" : "001"
},

{
 "order_statuses" : [
    "SUCCESS"
],
"year" : "2017",
"order_number" : "111"
}
```

Input 2: order_status = PARTLY_SUCCESS, below output should come

```
{
"order_statuses" : [
    "PARTLY_SUCCESS",
    "ON_HOLD",
    "INPROGRESS"
],
"year" : "2017",
"order_number" : "222"
```

}
With the help of this link [convert mysql query contains sum and group_concat to mongodb query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096432/convert-mysql-query-contains-sum-and-group-concat-to-mongodb-query) I have tried to get the desired result, but below query gives error "The field name '$addFields' cannot be an operator name". As i don't want to display count i tried adding to separate group but it didn't help.

```
db.order_summary.aggregate([

{"$project":{
    "schedule_datetime":1,
    "order_number ":1,
    "order_status":{"$ifNull":["$order_status",""]}
}},
{"$group":{
    "_id":{
    "order_number ":"$order_number ",
    "order_status":"$order_status"
    },
    "study_date":{"$first": "$study_date"}
}},
{"$sort":{"_id.order_status": 1}},
{"$group":{
    "_id":{
    "order_number ":"$_id.order_number "
    },
    "study_date":{"$first": "$study_date"},
    "order_status":{"$push": "$_id.order_status"}
}},
{"$group":{
    "_id":{
        "$substr":["$study_date",0,4]
    },
    "count":{
        "$sum":{
            "$cond": [
                {"$in": ["$order_status",[["SUCCESS"],["INPROGRESS","SUCCESS"]]]}, 

                1,0
             ]
        }
    },
    "order_numbers":{"$push":"$_id.order_number "},
    "$addFields":{"$size":"$order_numbers"},


}},
{"$match":{"order_numbers":{"$gt":0}}},
{"$sort":{"_id":-1}}
```

])

Could you please help to display the year and list of order_numbers as per above output, Thanks!

Comment: Move addFields into its own stage between group and match and remove the trailing space after order_number in push

Comment: I did that but it thrown error "FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.". When i try to assign like this {$addFields:{"order_numbers":{$size:"$accession_numbers"}}} It just print the total sum of order. Actually I don't want to display count and would like display Year and list of order_numbers. Please have a look for my output in question

Comment: I already tried this, it must displays for the matched status i.e count >0 but it displays all the order_numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query.

First `$group` to get distinct order number and status combination and pick the latest time stamp.

Second `$group` to get the grouping by year and status and pick all the order numbers.

`$match` to compare the status group against the input status.

```
db.order_summary.aggregate([
  {"$project":{
    "schedule_datetime":1,
    "order_number ":1,
    "order_status":{"$ifNull":["$order_status",""]
    }
  }},
  {"$sort":{"schedule_datetime":-1}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "order_number":"$order_number",
      "order_status":"$order_status"
    },
    "schedule_datetime":{"$first":"$schedule_datetime"}
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
       "year":{"$substr":["$schedule_datetime",0,4]},
       "order_number":"$_id.order_number"
      },
     "order_statuses":{"$push":"$_id.order_status"}
   }},
  {"$redact": {"$cond":[{"$in": ["SUCCESS","$order_statuses"]},"$$KEEP","$$PRUNE"]}},
  {"$sort":{"_id.year":-1}},
  {"$project":{"_id":0, "year":"$_id.year","order_number":"$_id.order_number", "order_statuses":1 }},
])
```

Comment: Updated answer to include grouping by status. Please take a look now.

Comment: Nope, output is coming 0 . `{"_id" : { "year" : "2018"},"order_numbers:[ ]}`.

Comment: Okay try now. There was trailing space in order status variable name in first group. Solution updated.

Comment: yeah, there is 1 more trailing space,output is coming now for both inputs. is it possible to just get year into _id?

Comment: I didn't follow you. Can you show me the expected output ?  `{"$project":{"_id.order_status":0}}` should remove the order status from final `_id` output and it should just be year.

Comment: Expected: `{"_id"  : "2017"}` instead `{"_id" : { "year" : "2017"}}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163331/discussion-between-shan-and-veeram).